# Force removal of index.php with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I'm currently using the following to rewrite `http://www.site.com/index.php/test/` to also work directly with `http://www.site.com/test/`, but I would like to not only allow the second version, I would like to FORCE the second version.  If a user goes to `http://www.site.com/index.php/test/` it should immediately reroute them to `http://www.site.com/test/`. index.php should never appear in a url. Stipulation: this should only apply to the first index.php.  If I have a title like `http://www.site.com/index.php/2011/06/08/remove-index.php-from-urls/` it should leave the second index.php, as it is part of the URL.

Current rule that allows but does not force:
    #Remove index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|css|js|robots.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, if a user goes to `http://www.site.com/index.php/test/` this rule will imediately reroute him to `http://www.site.com/test/`

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/(.*)/$ /$1
```

I'm not sure if that is what you need as your current rewrite rule is opposite to mine.

Comment: Thanks- Also elegant, but same comment as above. Not sure why it's redirecting continuously.

Comment: remove the following lines `#Remove index.php RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|css|js|robots.txt) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` and it will not go into an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

**First (and wrong) answer - see below**

You can accomplish a redirection with these directives (in this order):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|css|js|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

That will first **redirect** all the requests that begin with `index.php` to the corresponding shortened url, then silently serve `index.php/etc` with the second rule.

**EDIT - Please read on!**

In fact, the solution above generates an infinite redirection loop, because Apache takes the following actions (let's say we request `/index.php/abc`):

1. first `RewriteCond` matches
2. Apache redirects [R], that is, generates a new HTTP request, to `/abc`
3. `/abc` fails first `RewriteCond`
4. `/abc` matches second `RewriteCond`
5. Apache does not redirect, but rewrites this URI (so it makes an "hidden" request), to `/index.php/abc` . We are again at point 1, that's a loop.

Please note...

- By using the [L] (last rule) flag, we can only tell Apache not to process more rewrite rules, but only if the current rule matches. Since a new HTTP request is made, there is no information about how may redirection we have been through yet. So, any time one of the two matches, and in any case it generates a new request (=>loop)
- Using the [C] (chain rules) flag is kinda pointless because it makes Apache process a rule only if the previous rule matches, while the two rules we have are mutually excluding.
- Using the [NS] (not if subrequest) flag on rule #1 is again not an option because it aìsimply does not apply to our case (see [Apache RewriteRule docs](http://psort.mirror.edu.cn/manual/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) about it)
- Setting env variables is not an option (alas), since a new request is made at pt 2, thus destroying all environment variables we set.

An alternative solution can be to rewrite e.g. `/abc` , to `/index.php?path=abc`. That is done by these rules (please, delete your RedirectMatch similar rule before adding these):

```
RedirectMatch ^/index\.php(/.*) $1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php|images|css|js|robots.txt|favicon.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I don't know the internals of CodeIgniter's scripts, but as most of the MVC scripts, it will read `$_REQUEST['PATH_INFO']` to understand which page is requested. You could slightly modify the code that recognizes the page like this (I assumed that the page path is stored in the `$page` var):

```
$page = $_REQUEST['PATH_INFO'];
if(isset($_GET['path']) && strlen($_GET['path'])) $page = $_GET['path']; // Add this line
```

This won't break the previous code and accomplish what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you... this solution was elegant and looks like it should have worked, but codeigniter is arguing with it, and I'm getting a time out on "too many redirects." I have no idea why, because example.com/login works fine, its not like it redirect to example.com/index.php/login. Does anybody have thoughts, or know how to tell codeigniter's php not to use index.php urls? Thanks.